# How to generate .class files in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation

I need all these .java files to be compiled to .class files. so wherever a .java file is, i need to have their .class files generated there. How can i do it with netbeans.

[image]

I just wanted to compile all these as i do in command prompt using javac. Please help. I need .class files for an assignment related to software metrics.

Comment: I think that would be a maven setting...

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you know how to do it? Or is there a way to do it with command prompt using javac?

Comment: Right click the project node, select `Clean and Build`.  They classes are generated in the `target/classes` directory of your project.  You really, really want to avoid having them generated in your source directory as this can generate contamination as the files are not removed between builds

Comment: You're using a Maven based project, which is a dependency and and build system, you will want to keep using it to make sure that code is generated correctly

Answer (score 0):

sir, please follow this steps...
search for NetBeansProjects folder>>double click on project folder>>double click on build folder>>double click on classes folder>> Hear you can find .class files
thanks...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He is trying to determine how to compile the java files into class files, not find where they are located after building.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class files in the class folder inside of the build folder of your project. Go to your project's folder. You can get the Project's directory doing right click on the Project and then going to properties. Once you get the location, go into the folder and find the build folder. Look for the classes folder and click it. If your code is in a package, find the folder with the name of the package then inside of that folder, you should have the class files.

[image]